# ActiveMQ to HornetQ causes exception

Tags: activemq-classic, hornetq

I'm trying to send a JMS message using ActiveMQ to a server using HornetQ, and am having some difficulty. I would think that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do so I suspect there's some sort of (probably trivial) operator error on my end. Is there something that can be spotted here or something I should take a look at? The error happens when trying to create the session:

On my end, I'm doing the following:

```
 final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_USER, ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_PASSWORD, serverUrl);
 connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
 session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

On the server side they're seeing the following:

```
11:53:06,428 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl] (Old I/O server worker (parentId: 1778858866, [id: 0x6a073b72, -hostname-])) 
Failed to decode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type: 1
at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:550) [hornetq-core-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the ActiveMQ library to talk to HornetQ. Each one has its own protocol and you would require the proper libraries to talk, and that goes both ways. You can't use HornetQ libraries to talk to ActiveMQ.

You could use stomp to talk to HornetQ which is a common library between HornetQ and ActiveMQ.

Comment: Interesting. That was what my original thought was but the groups on both sides thought that sounded odd as it should be a wire protocol standard. I'll look into using stomp and/or adding HornetQ on our side.

Comment: Same way you can't use ActiveMQ to talk to WebSphere MQ.. etc..

You probably should accept my answer :)

Comment: Another option is to use Apache Camel to create a route that forwards messages from one Broker to the other.

Comment: Thanks guys. After some other hiccups I was at least able to communicate w/ their server using the hornetq jars. We try to minimize dependencies so might look into one of the other options, but at least now we know what the issue is.

Comment: JMS != Protocol...  JMS = client API not wire compatibility...

The only specs providing wire compatibility (i.e protocol) are:

AMQP, MQT, Stomp.. and there might be others but I can't remember now.


If you use an API implementation it will only be valid towards that specific implementation. 

I hope that helps!

Comment: This has changed now correct, you can use ActiveMQ Artemis to talk to HornetQ since HornetQ was donated to ActiveMQ - though I am struggling with how to get it to work O_o